# Search engine name issue

Tags: search, joomla, content-management-system, bing

I have an issue with the way my website is being searched on google.

Lets say my website is called `johnsmiths.com` but the actual business name is `John Smiths Sweets`.

When I search google for the full business name `John Smiths Sweets`, rather than just searching for the business, it is showing a link for the sweet section page on the website. Almost as if it is finding `johnsmiths.com` then adding sweets on to the search.

How do i get it so when someone searches for the full business name, it displays the home page link?

The search is working fine on google, but bing does not display it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done so:

1. I would start by setting up a [Google My Business account](https://www.google.com/business/) for your business and linking this account to your website.
2. Then open a [Google Webmaster account](https://www.google.com/webmasters/) and add your website
3. [Create an xml sitemap](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/) and add this to you Google Webmaster account (property > crawl > sitemaps > add sitemap)

You may need to do additional work but the above will take care of the essentials first.

Good luck!